# Change root node of TopNavigationMenu dynamically?

Tags: master-page, navigation

I have a main site with five subsites and they are all using the same masterpage. The main site is a national site and the subsites are local copies (same lists, libraries, pages, subsites etc). One list that is used by all sites is stored in the national site and I wish to not split it up. My problem is that when I am on a local site and click on an item from this list I am taken to the national site that has the national menu. If I can check where the user comes from (local site) can I override the default navigation and add the subsites as starting node? That would make the user think that they are still on the local site.

Please ask if you have any questions

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question looks too much confusing ..what is national and local? what is relation between list and navigation?and where you want to override?

Answer (score 1):

If the lists are in the same site collection, you could expose the list in a [content query web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx) or a [Data view web part.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-data-view-HA010094804.aspx)

This would display the list as it was on the subsites, while the list existed on the national site.